# How to convert a String to a generic type <E>?

Tags: java, string, generics, binary-tree

I have a binary tree `BinaryTree<E>` with the following variables

```
protected E data;
protected BinaryTree<E> left,right;
```

given to me by the professor and was asked to double the value of each node which I did successfully with the following code (only relevant code shown here):

```
if (data != null) {
  this.setData(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(getData().toString()) * 2));
}
```

Unfortunately this raises the following warning which I'd like to get rid of:

```
1 error found:
Error: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to E
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your assignment does not make sense. It's not possible to "double the value" of an arbitrary type. You should ask your professor to specify what exactly they meant.

Comment: @yole here are the instructions: Methods 6-8 assume that the strings stored in the binary tree are actually integers.  Your code will have to convert them to ints using the Integer.parseInt method. Of which: 7.    void doubles();

Double the integer value in every node of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement setData with E as the parameter. If you implement setData with input parameter type String, then it would throw an error that String cannot be converted to E. Refer code below:

```
public class BinaryTree<E> {
    E data;

    BinaryTree<E> left, right;

    public void doubleEachElement() {
        BinaryTree temp = this;
        if (temp != null) {
            if (temp.data != null) {
                temp.setData(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(temp.getData().toString()) * 2));
            }
            this.left.doubleEachElement();
            this.right.doubleEachElement();
        }
    }

    // private void setData(String valueOf) {// This would throw an error
    // stating the String cannot be converted to E
    // data = valueOf;
    // }
    public void setData(E valueOf) {
        data = valueOf;
    }

    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void printBTreeInorder() {
        BinaryTree temp = this;
        if (this != null) {
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        if (this.left != null)
            this.left.printBTreeInorder();
        if (this.right != null)
            this.right.printBTreeInorder();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree<Integer> intBTree = new BinaryTree<>();
        intBTree.setData(3);
        intBTree.printBTreeInorder();
        intBTree.doubleEachElement();
        intBTree.printBTreeInorder();
    }
}
```

The commented lines when uncommented lead to the same error that you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! Getting an uncalled check to setData though hmm

Answer (score 0):

Your BinaryTree is a generic type, so every time when you use 
this.setData(...) it would expect that whatever type you set inside it, it is of type E.

So your code would work, you will have to add E data type.

So, you have two solutions:

- remove E for your BinaryTree class, and your data field/methods will store "java.lang.Object" so you can set data directly as string or better as boxed double (new Double(... ) )
- where you use BinaryTree class, for example to your add value, use a specialized version of BinaryTree, like: BinaryTree node = new BinaryTreeNode(); node.setData(new Double (3.5));